# error in connecting java android to openLDAP

Tags: java, android, openldap, ldapconnection

I have installed openLDAP on my system with back end engine as LDAP. The details provided while installing it are :`Port-389,IPaddress-"192.168.....",
password-"secret"
,username-bindDN-"cn=name,cn=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com"`

I am trying to create a connection from android emulator to the LDAP server installed.I am using **unboundIdD LDAP SDK** for java.The code written is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

//String address="ldap://server1.mydomain.com";
String address="192.168.....";
int port=389;
String bindDN="CN=name,CN=users,DC=mydomain,DC=com";
String password="secret";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bt_login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_login);
    bt_login.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

       try {
        LDAPConnection c = new LDAPConnection(address,port,bindDN,password);

    } catch (LDAPException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


}

}
```

but on running this code on emulator..after **pressing login** button..I get an **Exception**.my error log is as follows:

`12-09 19:57:58.968: W/System.err(392): LDAPException(resultCode=52 (unavailable), errorMessage='Proxy operation retry failed', diagnosticMessage='Proxy operation retry failed')
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.bind(LDAPConnection.java:1837)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.<init>(LDAPConnection.java:637)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.<init>(LDAPConnection.java:534)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at gemini.ldapdemo2.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-09 19:57:58.972: W/System.err(392):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

why I am getting this exception.Please help me on this.I am a new guy on this.Thank you

Comment: That ldap exception means that the LDAP server is not running or is shutting down typically.

Comment: can you suggest me the steps of installing the openLDAP server.I downloaded it from [http://www.openldap.org/] .Is it a real LDAP server or not?Please help me.

Comment: The ldap administrator's quick start guide - http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html is pretty good for setting up an ldap server